# Is it necessary that properties file should be in resources folder in maven project?

Tags: gwt, maven-2

In maven project is it necessary that all the properties file,xml files needs to be in resources folder.Means if I want my properties file is in `src/main/java/com/search/search.properties`
then I need to put it in `resources/com/search/search.properties`.Is it necessary?

Because right now they are in java folder ,when I run maven project in hosted mode it runs properly. But when I create war it does not include that properties file in `war/web-inf/classes/com/search/search.properties`.

When I put it in `resources/com/search/search.properties` then and then only it include it in war folder.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Maven standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) you have to put Application/Library related resources into `src/main/resources`, if you do not do this, when maven want to package your application (War, Jar or ...) only copy resource in `src/main/resources` into your package.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you manage things. By default maven takes care if you use src/main/resources.

Also just verify that you have correct include/exclude tags in your resource tag under build.

```
<build>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
<build>
```